# Angular2- Can't call an API with a service in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, api

[Trying to call this API file in Angular through a service. I was able to call a local JSON file before with ease but this one is not working.[The second image is the table I want to setup for the data extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZzSp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqyKS.png)

[This is what I tried already for the service file. When I tried this for the path for the local JSON file, it worked, but the structure of this file is not allowing me to do the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxzmY.png)

Comment: what is your result when you subscribe to your getData method?

Answer (score 0):

".get()" is returning an observable, you have to subscribe to it in order to get the API response , or else nothing happens

```
this.http.get<any>(yourUrl).subscribe(data => {
    this.localVar = data;
})
```